# Next line escape character not working python

Tags: python, macos, unix

I used the following code to read from a text file line by line and print it on screen.

```
with open("source.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    print(content)
    print('\n')
f.close()
```

But the `\n` was just getting appended to the output and the output was coming in a single line instead. For example if the file was like this:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

the output was:

```
['abc\n', 'def\n', 'ghi']
```

Then I tried changing the single quotes with the `'\n'` with `"\n"` like this:

```
with open("source.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    print(content)
    print("\n")
f.close()
```

The actual output I need is:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

What can i do for that? Operating platform: Mac(Unix) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`rstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

```
>>> for i in content:
...     print i.rstrip()
... 
abc
def
ghi
```

The problem with your code is that it isn't doing what you would expect it to do. `content` is a list, and printing the list would just have `['abc\n', etc]`. You can use a for-loop (as I have shown) to go through each element in the list and individually print out all the elements on a separate line.

I'm not exactly sure why you have `print('\n')`, but I'm presuming that you come from another programming language. Python automatically adds a newline, so adding one is not needed :).

Finally, `rstrip()` is needed to strip the newline, otherwise this would appear:

```
>>> for i in L:
...     print i
... 
abc

def

ghi
```

Comment: Both the answers were able to solve my problem. Can any one tell me what was the problem with my code?

Comment: @HarikrishnanT I have added to my answer, does that help :3?

Comment: Ok thanks. Yes, I came from C and C++. Was just starting with python.

Answer (score 2):

You should do it this way:

```
with open('source.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f: #iterate over lines
        line = line.strip() #removes whitespaces and new lines
        print line #print the line, the print function adds new line
```

readlines() loads the whole file in memory and if the file is bigger than your memory you can't read it, so iterate over the file.

Comment: Both the answers were able to solve my problem. Can any one tell me what was the problem with my code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you were trying to print the list object itself, instead you should loop over the list and print individual items:

```
>>> lis = ['abc\n', 'def\n', 'ghi']
>>> print lis
['abc\n', 'def\n', 'ghi']
```

print lis actually prints the str representation of the list object:

```
>>> print str(lis)
['abc\n', 'def\n', 'ghi']
```

Loop over the list and print individual items. In python we can loop over the list itself unlike C/C++ where we require indexes.

```
>>> for item in lis:   
...     print item.rstrip('\n')  #removes the trailing '\n'
...     
abc
def
ghi
```

A for-loop over a list or any other iterable returns the next item from that iterable one by one and assigns it to the variable used in for-loop:

```
for x in lis:  #in each iteration x is assgined the next item from lis
   print x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('source.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    print content
```

Comment: Why is this better than the code in the question? Could you explain the principle behind your suggestion?